# I want to overwrite the document with the output of a function after clicking on the page

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

As you can see I've added an event listener to the whole page (Operating off the assumption that I know how that works) that waits for a click of the mouse to invoke a function called square with a single parameter. It multiplies whatever argument you pass to the parameter by itself and returns it as output. But instead of running `x` in the parameter, I want the user to be prompted for it, so I put that instruction in its place.

```js
document.addEventListener('click',console.log(square(window.prompt('input value', x))))

function square(x) {

 return x*x;
}
```

It's not working. I'd like to know why not and how to correct it, but I'm also open to entirely other solutions, as long as they are accompanied by detailed explanations.

Comment: Syntax Error: `Expected ')'`

Comment: That error is not in my local code. It is not what is causing it not to work. But I went ahead and corrected it here anyway. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Errors:

1. You where missing the closing `)` for `addEventListener`
2. You where using the undeclared variable `x` in `window.prompt('input value', x)` - just remove it
3. `document.write` will write the string into the document
4. Use an inlinefunction `function(){...your code...}` to avoid it triggering imediatly

Working code:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(){document.write(square(window.prompt('input value')))})

function square(x) {

  return x * x;
}
```

Comment: Okay so I don't need to put the x variable because `window.prompt('text')` acts as the argument? Cool I'll fix that. But I'm still not getting the text to show up on my document. Why not?

Comment: `console.log` will show it in your browsers *console*. Where do you want it to show?

Comment: On the document page. I assumed having `document.addEventListener` would direct the output there.

Comment: Okay so the only problem now is that it seems to be prompting the user as soon as the document loads, instead of when the user clicks on the document

Comment: Bingo! That did it. I'm guessing the reason the `window.prompt` was triggering immediately is because it was on the same line as the listener. Is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98495/discussion-between-codeisir-and-musixauce3000).